# Is it a good approach to create a Docker image from GitHub source code and run it as a container on a production server?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a GitHub repository containing the source code for my application. I'm considering using Docker to containerize and deploy the application on a production server. My current approach involves cloning the repository and using Docker Compose to build and run the container.

Here are the steps I follow:

1. Clone the repository: `git clone git@github.com:Tokariev/somerepo.git`
2. Build the Docker image using a development-specific Docker Compose
   file:  `docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml build`
3. Run the container on the production server using a
   production-specific Docker Compose file: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up`

I would like to know if this approach is considered a good practice for deploying applications in a production environment. Are there any potential pitfalls or security concerns I should be aware of? Are there alternative methods or best practices that I should consider instead?

Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The approach you're describing seems more or less routine; you're missing a `push` step, and often you'd have a CI system actually do the build, but "check out source code, build and push an image, and then run it somewhere else" is a pretty normal workflow.

Comment: I don't make any push image to docker hub (just make `git push` to the GitHub repo). The image that I use later is creating on the production server directly. After that I start the docker container.

Comment: One very standard approach is to avoid having any development tools on the production server at all; don't `git` anything on the server, _only_ run images that you've built somewhere else, tested, and pushed to a repository.